# Sending mail via C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am trying to send an email to myself via C# using gmail stmp server but I  was getting an email from the gmail team saying **"Google just blocked a less secure app from accessing your Google Account."** . Now I have changed the settings to allow less secure apps to sign in google but I am not able send an email to myself.Below is my code.

```
    private static string sendMail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm)
    {
        try
        {
            string smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
            string userName = "myemail@gmail.com";//write your email address
            string password = "xxxxxx";//write password
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            mClient.Port = 587;
            mClient.EnableSsl = true;
            mClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            mClient.Host = smtpHost;
            mClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            mClient.Send(mm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        return "Send Sucessfully";
    }
private void f()
      {
          i = i + 1;
        string sysName = string.Empty;
        string sysUser = string.Empty;
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress toAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress fromAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        sysName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
        sysUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();
        mm.Subject = sysName + " " + sysUser;
        string filename = string.Empty;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        MessageBox.Show(sendMail(mm).ToString());
        //sendMail(mm);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f();
    }
```

Also I tried the same with my yahoo account.Then also I didnt receive any email at all.
I had changed port to 465 and smtphost to "mail.yahoo.com" and email address to mymail@yahoo.com

Comment: If you search in the world's favorite search engine for "Google just blocked a less secure app from accessing your Google Account", the top link explains perfectly clearly what to do. [Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). Is this solution is unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: @spender I just did, got two results, neither of them much helpful.

Comment: So, turning on the account setting "Access for less secure apps" doesn't work for you then? You've definitely done this, yes?

Comment: Does that mean it dint work even after enabling "allow less secure applications" in google account? Or are you looking for a better solution without compromising the security?

Comment: If turning on the "Access for less secure apps" option isn't good, it looks like you have to do an oauth dance... Here are the details: https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: So, turning on the account setting "Access for less secure apps" doesn't work for me. I am unable send an email

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "Gmail@gmail.com";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString(); 
    //Password of your gmail address
    const string fromPassword = "Password";
     // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
    string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
    body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

you have use this code .
it is running code.

Answer (score -1):

Go to google account settings, and allow less secure applications.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security?utm_source=OGB#signin
At the bottom "Allow less secure apps" slider is the one you need to use.

Default google SMTP settings are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server).

Comment: You need to improve this answer.  Maybe some steps on how to do that at google?  Maybe some supporting docs?  Usually (though not always), you can tell you need to improve your answer when it's one sentence, especially when it doesn't even wrap to two lines.  Just a rule of thumb I have, though.

Comment: Yes, was looking @ google account settings to find direct link.

Comment: For example, if you copy/pasted spender's comment under the OP's question, it's already a much better answer (I'm not saying you should plagiarize him...)

Comment: No point in copy paste :) As long as it helps him/her resolve issue - that's all that matters.

Comment: Linked article does not answer the question.